# Python Virtualenv: Do I need to run a script when/if I create a new file in a Virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have the following code in two different files in the same directory which were made after the virtual environment was made.

**main.py:**

```
from second_file import important_function

def calling_function():
    x = 1
    instance = important_function(x)
    print(instance)
```

**second_file.py:**

```
def important_function(x):
    return(x + 5)
```

However, before the program even gets to `calling_function`, I receive `important_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`. I think I am giving parameters to the functions correctly between files as I can do this with other files which makes me think that it's a problem with virtualenv. Do I need to run a script or something to get the files to work in the virtualenv or is my code just wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Is somebody able to reproduce the error? I can not (like I expected). I'm pretty sure you just call this function somewhere else, or redefine it somewhere else or stuff like that. Provide an example that we can reproduce please. This is not related with venv, venv does not works like that

Comment: Please give me the following information, do you have a if __name__ == ''__main__" block inside second_file.py or some how that function is getting called within that file?  how are you executing your program? what python version are you using?

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: I added calling_function() to main.py and it worked perfectly In my experience a virtualenv will only complain if you try to run code with a module not installed (edited)